# Getting the error "HTTP 400 - Bad Request (Request Header too long)"

Tags: authentication, iis, active-directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/kerberos-authentication-problems-if-user-belongs-to-groups

We are having this issue with an internal application.

This topic has been covered before but I am still at a loss as to the resolution. Only some users are getting this error. Some users don't get the error and are members of WAY MORE AD groups than the users who get the error.

The error does not occur if instead of a DNS alias, the user uses a fully-qualified name or the IP address. The error does not occur if user uses IE11 -which we are about to desupport.

Our app doesn't require these AD tokens to be sent. Is there some IIS setting or browser setting that can prevent the tokens being sent and causing this error? Is the only resolution involve making those registry settings on the desktop computers of users having the issue?

Comment: This link should help you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-bad-request-response-kerberos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-bad-request-response-kerberos).

Comment: It provided info but did not resolve the issue. We set those registry values on the web server to no avail. The other article said that these settings much be made on every tier: desktop, web server, database server. And I'm still looking for answer to questions in my original post.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.